# Troubleshooting serial communication from Python to Arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I'm using software which has Python scripting capabilities. I want to use it to move a Clearpath servo and run internal software commands intermittently.

Using an Arduino, I can control the servo, but it starts going wrong once I start using serial communication. After reading through other post, I'm thinking the problems are arising because serial communication is 8bit and I'm wanting to send large int.

For example, a section of the Arduino code shows:

```
void loop(){  
 if(Serial.available()){
 inByte = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
 ser = inByte.toInt();
 X.move(ser);
 while(!X.commandDone()||!X.readHLFB())
 { }
 Serial.print (inByte);
 delay(1000);
 }
}
```

Before I started using serial communication, I'd utilize integers in X.move(ser) and get flawless results. Now that I'm using the serial port, I can tell there's something wrong with this code. Even though it seems to work using the Serial Monitor, the more I try it (especially using larger numbers) the more I realize its probably not doing what it did before I used serial.

Then add Python into the mix and it gets even worse.
To give you an idea of what I'm trying to do, here was an example of Python code:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)
ser.close()
ser.open()
while True:
    var = "1000"
    ser.write(var.encode())
    time.sleep(1)'
```

Using this code, the servo moves but it's not right at all.
How can I send large integers (for example, 50502) from Python to Arduino through serial without it getting mangled during serial communication?

Comment: use python 'struct" library with the 'pack' and 'unpack' function...with this you can convert a big entiger in a serie of byte (with the given endianness) and all you need to do is send this byte in serie

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to pack the number into a series of bytes, but haven't been able to figure out how interpret it on the Arduino side.

Comment: you need to implement a kind of commnication protocol: a mark to tell the start of transmission and another mark to tell the end of the transmission